# How can I view custom events in Chatbase?

Tags: chatbase

I am currently trying to integrate Chatbase into my Google Action project.

I want to use the Custom Events API (https://chatbase.com/documentation/events#documentation) to track purchases via my action.

Unfortunately if I send custom events to Chatbase, they don't show up in any reporting view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Sean with Chatbase support. It is on our roadmap to surface custom events in the [funnels report](https://chatbase.com/documentation/funnels), however other priorities have delayed the release. Please stay tuned to the [Chatbase Blog](https://blog.chatbase.com/) for updates on new feature releases.